# Unable to get ng2-bootstrap

Tags: angular, ng2-bootstrap

Here's my app.ts file:

```
import {bootstrap}    from 'angular2/platform/browser'
import {AppComponent} from './app.component'
bootstrap(AppComponent);
```

Here's my app.component.ts file:

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
import {Alert} from 'ng2-bootstrap/ng2-bootstrap';
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template:`
    <alert type="info">ng2-bootstrap hello world!</alert>
  `,
  directives: [Alert] 
})
export class AppComponent {
}
```

I get this error [image]

Comment: Most like you're missing a configuration like [here](https://github.com/valor-software/ng2-play/commit/2eac15a7e2a5f1b243ed2b9bb3d7fbf99a18d52f#diff-eacf331f0ffc35d4b482f1d15a887d3bR28) (assuming you're using SystemJS)

Answer (score 2):

I got this to work by configuring my script in my index.html:

```
<script>
      System.config({
        packages: {       
          app: {
            format: 'register',
            defaultExtension: 'js'
          },
          "node_modules/ng2-bootstrap": {
              defaultExtension: 'js'
           }
        },
        paths: {
            "ng2-bootstrap/ng2-bootstrap":   "node_modules/ng2-bootstrap/ng2-bootstrap",
            "angular_material/material":   "node_modules/angular_material/material",
            "moment":   "node_modules/ng2-bootstrap/node_modules/moment/moment"
          }
      });
      System.import('app/main')
            .then(null, console.error.bind(console));
    </script>
```

Also, do not forget to add the bootstrap style

```
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Answer (score 0):

In case that someone still have the issue I use this config, just added the moment config in the app section of the System.config:

```
"node_modules/moment": {
                    defaultExtension: 'js'

      }
```

this is the complete System.config

```
System.config({
            packages: {
                app: {
                    format: 'register',
                    defaultExtension: 'js'
                },
                "node_modules/ng2-bootstrap": {
                    defaultExtension: 'js'
                },
               //Added moment in app section
                "node_modules/moment": {
                    defaultExtension: 'js'
                }
            },
            paths: {
                "ng2-bootstrap/ng2-bootstrap": "node_modules/ng2-bootstrap/ng2-bootstrap",
                "angular_material/material": "node_modules/angular_material/material",
                "moment": "node_modules/moment/moment"
            }
        });
```